# Conditionals in LaTeX: try/catch and "not \equal"

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, class-options

I have a problem with some variable checking: I offer the user an option in the interface of a document class. If the option is not provided my code fails. Hence I would like to check if the option has been provided or not. In other programming environments I would do this with TRY/CATCH of "!=" not equal. How do I do this in LaTeX?

A minimal example looks like this:

1) document class `minimalExample.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{FAIRControlledDocument}[2017/07/03 minimalExample]

\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\providecommand{\theVariable}[1]{\@empty}
\DeclareOptionX{docoption}{%
    \def\theVariable{#1}%
}

\ProcessOptionsX

% pre-defined document types
\ifdefined\theVariable
\ifthenelse{\equal{\theVariable}{a} \OR \equal{\theVariable}{b}}{%
    \providecommand\fcd@type@xx{some text}%
}{}
\fi
```

2) working `minimalExample.tex`:

```
\documentclass[docoption=a]{minimalExample}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

3) crashing `minimalExample.tex`:

```
\documentclass[]{minimalExample}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I would like to check if variable `\theVariable` has a value if it is not provided and bypass the crashing code if not. Any ideas?

Comment: Just remove the `\providecommand{\theVariable}` line: you're later checking whether it exists with `\ifdefined`, aren't you?

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the `\providecommand{\theVariable}` line: you're later checking whether it exists with `\ifdefined`, aren't you?

However, if you later need to check whether it equals `\@empty`, then do like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{FAIRControlledDocument}[2017/07/03 minimalExample]

\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\newcommand*{\theVariable}{}
\DeclareOptionX{docoption}{%
    \def\theVariable{#1}%
}

\ProcessOptionsX

% pre-defined document types
\ifthenelse{\equal{\theVariable}{a} \OR \equal{\theVariable}{b}}{%
    \providecommand\fcd@type@xx{some text}%
}{}
```

Note `\newcommand*` instead of `\providecommand` (and no argument); note also that I define `\theVariable` to be empty by default, so a check

```
\ifx\theVariable\@empty
```

would succeed. It wouldn't if you do `\newcommand*{\theVariable}{\@empty}`, because in this case the replacement text of `\theVariable` is not empty: a box containing an empty box is not empty, is it?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is rather simple. Your default definition of `\theVariable` requires an argument while the one you define if the option is used doesn't, so you have two different definitions depending on the usage of the option. The code fails, because you don't provide an argument to `\theVariable` while it requests one.

Too fix this, just use `\providecommand*{\theVariable}{\@empty}`. Note that I added the `*` because you don't need `\theVariable` to be long since it doesn't accept arguments any way.

So your .cls should look like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{FAIRControlledDocument}[2017/07/03 minimalExample]

\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\providecommand*{\theVariable}{\@empty}
\DeclareOptionX{docoption}{%
    \def\theVariable{#1}%
}

\ProcessOptionsX\relax

% pre-defined document types
\ifdefined\theVariable
\ifthenelse{\equal{\theVariable}{a} \OR \equal{\theVariable}{b}}{%
    \providecommand\fcd@type@xx{some text}%
}{}
\fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the approaches of egreg and Skillmon but didn't manage to get the code running. Finally I managed to solve my actual problem the the following class definition:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{FAIRControlledDocument}[2017/07/03 minimalExample]

\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

%\providecommand{\theVariable}[1]{\@empty} <-- Do not defined this variable
\DeclareOptionX{docoption}{%
    \def\theVariable{#1}%
}

\ProcessOptionsX

% pre-defined document types
\ifdefined\theVariable
\ifthenelse{\equal{\theVariable}{a} \OR \equal{\theVariable}{b}}{%
    \providecommand\fcd@type@xx{some text}%
}{}
\else
   \def\documentLanguage{xx} <-- set some special value for later use
\fi
```

Still, my larger question about try/catch is not answered, but I will close the problem as "solved" - my code works now

Comment: As far as I know there is no exception handling you can use like with python or similar languages -- to answer your question.